# ADFS Sliding Expiration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, authentication, adfs

We are using `ADFS` to authenticate our sharepoint application and now the application get expires base on the `TokenLifetime` of `ADFS`. We want to set it as sliding expiration, such that it will not expire the session when a user is working on the page. How to set the sliding expiration for `ADFS` authentication ?

Answer (score 2):

ADFS: The TokenLifetime property can be set at the ADFS end using the command upon creation . Below is example is for 2 sec . Set this value to a high number ,so that the session never expires while working on page .

```
Add-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -Name "abc" -Identifier "https://abc/_trust/" -WsFedEndpoint "https://abc/_trust/" -TokenLifetime 2 -SignatureAlgorithm http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
```

STS: The STS config maintains the value of LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow by default is 10min .
$sts.LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow

```
WindowsTokenLifetime - LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow = Concept of Sliding Session
```

Consider Eg - tokenlifetime(ADFS) = 30 min and logontokenexpirationwindow(EW) = 10 min , (TL)30-(EW)10 = 20 min the session expires .
PS http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scicoria/archive/2011/06/10/sharepoint-2010-fba-and-sliding-sessions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can read this post. It should point you to the right direction:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446526.aspx