# ADFS and SharePoint 2013: Re-authenticating every 4 minutes

Tags: authentication, adfs, security-token-service

We have our token to expire after 10 hours, but every 4-5 minutes SharePoint goes out and re-authenticates against the token. Browser activity doesn't matter. How do we keep SharePoint from re-authenticating against the token? I feel like this has something to do with the FedAuth cookie, but not sure.

Comment: check from AD server what is Web SSO Lifetime value, can you run this Get-ADFSProperties on AD server? also on sharepoint server run this Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig and share the output...

Comment: Which variables do you want to see?

Comment: web lifetoken from adfs and logontokencache

Comment: Okay. I won't be able to get those until probably Monday. Am I wrong in thinking that its probably a SharePoint setting issues since other apps use that same token and they don't have timeout issues?

Comment: [screenshot of get-spsecuritytokenserviceconfig](http://i.imgur.com/dpwjfyh.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

**Enable STS Session Cookie**

```
$sts = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$sts.UseSessionCookies = $true
$sts.Update()
```

LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow for the SharePoint STS is 10 minutes. The relying party by default it sets the token lifetime in ADFS to be 2 minutes.

**LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow in SharePoint**

```
$sts = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$sts.LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow = (New-TimeSpan –minutes 1)
$sts.Update()
```

Then do an `IISRESET`

Comment: What does enabling the STS session cookie do? Currently it is disabled.

Comment: I was giving you hints which you can try. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh147183(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I don't want to use session cookies because it breaks office integration.

Comment: Then you can change the `LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow`

Comment: This is already set to 10 minutes but its timing out way before that

Answer (score 1):

Set the ADFS value to high number like 10 hrs and set the sharepoint token expiration cache to lower value 20min(not 10 hrs) .

[ADFS Sliding Expiration](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97498/adfs-sliding-expiration/116993#116993)

[SharePoint 2013 ADFS login local token cache always expired](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79864/sharepoint-2013-adfs-login-local-token-cache-always-expired/81310#81310)

Comment: The windowstokenlifetime is set to 10 hours and the LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow is set to 10 minutes

Comment: [screenshot of get-spsecuritytokenserviceconfig](http://i.imgur.com/dpwjfyh.jpg)

Comment: The adfs value should be less . u have to do it on adfs server

Comment: OK, which value is the adfs value?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how helpful it will be, but we were also suffering from the same issue.  Turns out it had nothing to do with the cache or token at all, but instead had to do with how many users could be cached per web front end.  The default for SP 2013 is only 250 users, so as soon as user 251 logs in, it invalidates the cache for user 1.  Then user 252 invalidates 2 and so on.  In any decent sized organization this can lead to a round-robin of invalidation.  We fixed with the following PowerShell script.

```
$maxTokens = 5000
$sts = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$sts.MaxServiceTokenCacheItems = $maxTokens
$sts.MaxLogonTokenCacheItems = $maxTokens
$sts.Update()
iisreset
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this?

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/954bf5e8-0a32-485d-97e0-7b842e315edc/fedauth-cookie-expiration-adfs-in-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointadminprevious

> SharePoint calculates the expiration of the cookie with the following
>   formula:
>
> SAML Token Lifetime – Logon Token Cache Expiration Window

This forum post suggests to do this:

**Run this command on ADFS, then start/stop ADFS after this is ran (not restart)** (looks like this is already set correctly based on your screenshot in one of the comments above)

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.ADFS.PowerShell  
Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust –TargetName "[ourrelayingpartytrustreference]" –TokenLifeTime 10
```

**Run on sharepoint server:**

```
$sts = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$sts.LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow = (New-Timespan -Minutes 500)
$sts.Update()
iisreset
```

(I set it to 500 min here, but set it to however long you want it to be)

Did you try this yet? Hope this helps... sorry if it's just noise.